# Set tag or unique identifier for MSMessage

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, msmessage

It is possible to set a unique `id` and or `tag` for a `MSMessage` instance? My current app is based on data fetched from a server using an integer id as an identifier. When a previous message is selected I want to modify the view accordingly by fetching the `id` or `tag` (if possible) of the current message and using that in a query to my server.

```
  override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
    //Retrive id from selected message
    if conversation.selectedMessage != nil{
      //Do things
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the URL of the message to add in it an "id" key:

```
guard let components = NSURLComponents(string: myBaseURL) else {
    fatalError("Invalid base url")
}

let id = NSURLQueryItem(name: "id", value: yourIdHere)
components.queryItems = [id]

guard let url = components.url  else {
    fatalError("Invalid URL components.")
}

message.url = url
```

Use an hash of the date for your id or whatever you want